# Query upgrade and cross index search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query which was originally written for ES 1.5.

The query has two issues:

- No query.filtered anymore. Transform query to use [bool/must](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)
- No *type* anymore, thus *idea.title* and *challenge.title* are actually two different indexes.

How do I run a query cross-index?

```
{
    "_source": [
        "id",
        "org_id",
        "author_id",
        "idea_id",
        "challenge_id",
        "bulletin_id",
        "comment",
        "title",
        "description",
        "name",
        "created_at"
    ],
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "terms": {
                            "org_id": [
                                563
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "idea.title": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "idea.description": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "challenge.title": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "challenge.description": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "bulletin.title": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "bulletin.description": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "comment_idea.comment": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "comment_challenge.comment": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "comment_bulletin.comment": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "files_idea.name": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "files_idea.content": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "files_challenge.name": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "files_challenge.content": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "files_bulletin.name": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "files_bulletin.content": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "groups.name": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "users.name": "test"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "tags.name": "test"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "users.type_priority": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        "_score"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to run this query on multiple indices?

Comment: Correct. I have created an index for every type and now working on migrating queries.